# How do I dynamically decide which hash to add a value to?

Tags: ruby

I have a class that has hashes in various stages of "completion".  This is to optimize so that I don't have to keep recreating hashes with root data that I already know.  For example this is a counter called @root that would serve as a starting point.

```
{3=>4, 4=>1, 10=>3, 12=>5, 17=>1}
```

and it took key+key+key+key+key number of iterations to create @root.  But now I have all combinations of [x,y] left to be added to the counter and individually evaluated.  So I could do it like:

```
a = (1..52)
a.combination{|x,y|
  evaluate(x,y)
}
```

But instead of I would like to do this:

```
a.each{|x| 
  evaluate(x, "foo")
  a.each {|y| evaluate(y, "bar")}
}
```

Where i have a method like this to keep track of the hash at each state:

```
def evaluate index, hsh
    case hsh
    when "root"
        @root.key?(index) ? @root[index] += 1 : @root[index] = 1
    when "foo"
        @foo = @root.clone
        @foo.key?(index) ? @foo[index] += 1 : @foo[index] = 1
    when "bar"
        @bar = @foo.clone
        @bar.key?(index) ? @bar[index] += 1 : @bar[index] = 1
    end
end
```

But there is alot of repetition in this method. Is there a way that I could do this dynamically without using eval?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This looks like a small part of a larger issue, and doesn't make a lot of sense. Maybe explaining what you want to do in the larger picture will help us help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `hsh` as a string descriptor, you can directly pass the `hash` object as parameter to your method `evaluate`? E.g. instead of `evaluate(x, "foo")` you write

```
@foo = @root.clone
evaluate(x, @foo)
```

Also note the `@root.clone` in your code overwrites the field several times inside the loop.

Additionally if you use a default initializer for your hash you save quite some logic in your code. E.g. the code lines

```
h = Hash.new{0}
...
h[index] += 1
```

will set the default value to zero if non was set for `index`. Thus you do not have to take care of the special case inside your `evaluate` method.

Comment: I didn't make it clear in the code because I didn't think it was important, but evaluate is in another object and the caller of evaluate wouldn't have any knowledge of what the different hashes were called.  I guess I could give it knowledge, but it would break encapsulation in a messy way.

Comment: Sounds like a strange design. But you still can do something like that: `{"root"=>@root,"foo"=>@foo,"bar"=>@bar}[hsh][index] += 1`. If you assign the hash to a constant it doesn't look as bad ;-)